# How to get ping interval in libwebsocket?

Tags: c, socket.io, libwebsockets

I am using libwebsocket as client to communicate with socketIO. I want to keep my connection alive by sending ping packet. I know during protocol negotiation we get ping interval and ping timeout. But I am failing to find it in libwebsocket context.

Comment: How is ICMP is going to help you implement a keep alive?

Comment: you are confusing ICMP ping packet with ping-pong mechanism in websocket

Comment: Probably. Can we see some code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I removed the chit-chat from your question (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)) we don't want people to have to wade through non-essentials on every question. Code, available output, expected output and/or error message should be included by editing your question.